# Apply a review comment to a particular commit in a pull request

Tags: github

I received a pull request that contains several commits. One of the commits requires a change. So I click on the commit title, then use the green *Review changes* button in the upper right, insert my comment and then use *Submit review*.

I expected the comment to be somehow attached to the commit, but that does not happen. Instead, it appears in the general conversation about the entire pull request.

How can I attach a review comment to a particular commit? Notably, I want to say "This patch must change in such and such way", and then it must be clear what "This patch" is that I commented on. Moreover, is it possible to have a conversation about "this patch" and this patch only, such that the comments are not intermingled with comments on other patches in the pull request?

Comment: You can comment on specific lines and suggest changes to apply as shown in https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/reviewing-changes-in-pull-requests/reviewing-proposed-changes-in-a-pull-request

Comment: In this case, the commit message needed a change. Is there a place to note it? I found nothing the provided link.

Comment: Then no. Suggesting a change to a commit message doesn't really make sense in GitHub's PR model, because that changes _the commit_, rewriting history, whereas the other suggestions would add new commits to the source branch.

Comment: Ah, ok. A contribution model that excludes history rewriting doesn't fit my expectations at all and explains why I mostly had to curse at Github's behavior than to praise it.