# How to sort files in a pull request or in a commit?

Tags: git, github, aws-codecommit

I'm opening a PR for a project and I want my senior developer to look at it, but my PR has wrong order of files and changes that if you want to understand the problem my PR solves, you would need to go to 2nd page first, and only then to first and it creates this messy behavior where you will go to the 2nd page, then to 1st, then again to 2nd and so on.

I want a possibility of sorting files my way, so that firstly you would see the most important changes and only then tests for these changes and only then some sugar style changes, for example

I tried to google but only found docs on how to sort just PRs

Comment: The solution is not a technical, but a communicational one. Write a memo in the PR description on how the files are supposed to be reviewed.

Comment: @RomainValeri, is there a technical solution that would sort changes that are showing?

Comment: My advice is: do not create pull requests that are that big and do many things at once. Instead split it into a series of small PRs where every single PR concentrates on one small step.

Comment: I agree with @phd's advice in general. Another possible alternative is to have separate commits that "tell a story", and ask the reviewer to review the commits in order, rather than all the files taken from the POV of a single merge. AFAIK there isn't a way to change the presentation order of the files.

Comment: It is a shortcoming of the Github way of doing things that you cannot review changes per commit. [I have been told](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75667194/apply-a-review-comment-to-a-particular-commit-in-a-pull-request#comment133491543_75667194) that you can only review changes as a whole regardless of over how many commits they are distributed. This makes Github's review system less than useful.

Comment: @j6t Actually, I think I'd prefer that, compared to how AzDO does it- where I believe if you leave a comment on a commit it shows up only on the commit and not in the PR at all, which means the PR can still be completed without resolving that comment, and if no one specifically views each commit separately, it may go completely unnoticed.

Comment: @TTT, thx for the comment and basically an answer. We have tests for everything and I'd like tests to be after the code. AWS CodeCommit's comments on commits doesn't show up properly on PR and could be ignored accidentally. Separating by PRs seems wrong logically, tests should be with the code. Separating with commits is inconvenient, strange that such a simple visual thing isn't present